Making text line up vertically when sharing to WhatsApp
I've created a simple scorecard app, that sums users scores while they're playing games (card games, golf etc). I've added in the ability to share the result of their game to WhatsApp and I'd like it to appear a bit like a table, with the player name and then the player score, each player on a new line.
I'm trying to make the scores line up vertically, which is challenging given the player names will differ in length. I did this successfully in my IDE on my laptop by working out the length of the longest name and adding the correct amount of whitespace to the shorter names. This prints out to the terminal correctly, like so:

However, when I share to WhatsApp in my app on my android phone the text no longer lines up. I understand this is due to the font used by whatsapp, where an "i" takes up less space than a "w", whereas I need it to be monospaced.
Here's how it currently appears on my phone:

Any ideas on how I could get it to line up neatly on WhatsApp?

maybe convert to image and send as image

In documentation for WhatsApp I found How to format your messages
It shows it can use some markdown formatting.

You can put text in single backtick  `text` to display it in monospace font as inline code

You can put text in three backticks ```text``` to have multiline text in monospace font.




Thank you, I also just noticed that three backticks either side (```text here`` ) will convert the text to monospaced and solve my issue! Thanks for the response
